# css image overlays and inline block in UIwebview

Tags: iphone, css, uiwebview

On an iOS app I'm trying to list all images from the user gallery, float a clickable red x in the top left (or right) corner of each and have the display in a grid pattern, what I have here works in my browser but when I run it in phonegap it does not display correctly in iOS or android. I am not sure where to go from here or if it's even possible, I am using jQuery mobile if that matters. I tried to run the code without the jQuery and received the same results..

```
<span id="client_logos">
    <div class="imgspan">
        <img src="img1.jpg" width="118" height="118" alt="" border="0" class="timg">
        <a href=""><img src="icon-folder.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="" border="0" class="fimg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="imgspan">
        <img src="img2.jpg" width="118" height="118" alt="" border="0" class="timg">
        <a href=""><img src="icon-folder.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="" border="0" class="fimg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="imgspan">
        <img src="img3.jpg" width="118" height="118" alt="" border="0" class="timg">
        <a href=""><img src="icon-folder.gif" width="28" height="28" alt="" border="0" class="fimg"></a>
    </div>
</span>
```

my css is:

```
.client_logos {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.timg {
    position:absolute;
}
.fimg {
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
}
.imgspan {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw many mistakes on your code, that maybe the problem:

1. Span `#client_logos` should be a div because its not right wrap html elements inside a span.
2. CSS is declared `.clients_logos`, but your span is using ID and no class at all.
3. `fimg` and `timg` is using `position: absolute`, but his parent `.imgspan` doesn't have a position, you should add a position:

   ```
   .imgspan {
       display: inline-block;
       margin: 0 5px;
       width:120px;
       height:120px;
   }
   ```